# Is there a way to convert a file to .dwg?

Tags: file-formats

I can download a file from Tinkercad as any of these:

```
.STL
.OBJ
.X3D
.VRML
```

Is there a way to convert any of those file types to .DWG?

Answer (score 1):

I found this site and tested it a moment ago. I uploaded a simple .STL file (crystal) and had to register as a user (free, unremarkable) in order to perform the conversion.

http://www.cadforum.cz/catalog_en/stl2dwg.asp

The downloaded file was in .DWG format and opened without a problem in AutoCAD 2013 as a 3d object.

Note the placement of the pivot point in Meshmixer (first image) and the corresponding location in AutoCAD.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I managed to download the file as a .DXF. Will that open in AutoCAD?

Comment: It should, as well as open in many other CAD type programs. DXF means drawing exchange format.

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions with instant delivery/conversion, and others that take some hours to send you the file. 
I found solutions varying from free online conversion to pricey service.
You may need to do some touch up on the files converted from automated platform before you send it to a CNC or other CAD/CAM machine.
You can check on these platforms:
http://cadmesh.com
https://www.convertcadfiles.com/

Have in mind that, the higher is the model complexity (shape) the harder is to convert the model.
If trying to convert a 3D scanned model, make sure to have a closed mesh and a high-density mesh definition.
Good luck!